# Variable limit in For loop Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to set a variable limit in a for loop where the variable is actually changed? Something like this

```
Set sht = Worksheets(2)

For i = 1 To sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    [instructions that may or may not insert new rows]
Next i
```

In my case, inside for loop the data range might grow only but still I need to go through all of it.

In other words, is the top limit updated in every iteration?

Comment: did you try looping backwards?

Comment: If you need to insert (or delete) rows in a loop, it's often better to start at the bottom and work up, otherwise you'll oftentimes get unexpected results.

Comment: Use a while loop and increment the upper bound each time you add a new row. A while loop in VBA can be done in three different forms: 1) `Do While ... Loop`. 2) `Do Until ... Loop` 3) `While ... Wend`.

Comment: If it inserts or not, depends on rows above, so I can't loop backwards. Probably a while-loop will do better.

Comment: Just to answer your original question: The top limit of a `For Next` loop can not be updated within that loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task for a `Do While/Until Loop` rather than a `For Next`. Assuming your rows are inserted below the current one:

```
currentRow = 1 '<-- or wherever your row starts
Do While Cells(currentRow, yourColumn) <> "" '<-- assuming your "stop" is the first empty row, as I understand for how you define the upper bound of your loop
    '[maybe insert a row]
    currentRow = currentRow + 1 '<-- increase the current row to scan the next one (if you inserted a row just below, it will be the one you just inserted). 
Loop
```

Just as a rule of thumb, `For Next` loops are designed for lengths that you know before starting the loop, while `Do While/Until` loops are designed for lengths that you don't know before you start the loop.

Comment: @Javier your column is yours to define. I assume you're checking the content of a specific cell to decide whether to continue the loop or stop it, and  `Cells()` takes both row and input. So `currentRow` would be the moving index for the row, but the column index is up to you to choose it (`1` if you check the cell in the first column, `2` in the second etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a loop over all rows. It stops, if your current row is the last used row in column 1:

```
Private Sub LoopOverAllNewRows()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set sht = Worksheets(2)
    i = 0
    Do
       i = i + 1
       ' [instructions that may or may not insert new rows]
       ' If SomethingWentWrong Then Exit Do
    Loop Until i = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

To prevent endlees looping you may want to insert an additional `Exit Do` condition.

Answer (score 0):

## The For Next Loop

### VBA Help

```
For counter = start To end

Next [counter]
```

### A Small Study

The following is how I see the `For Next` loop working. Some statements are at least not correct and probably not entirely true.

```
Sub ForNext()
    Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 to 3
        Msgbox i
    Next ' or Next i
    Msgbox "You might have thought that 'i' is '3' now, but it isn't. It is '" & i & "'". 
End Sub
```

---

The following two things cannot be changed:

```
start = 1
end = 3
```

**Round 1:**
`start` (1) is written to `counter` (i=1).
`Msgbox` displays `counter` (i=1).
`Next` increases `counter` (i=2).
`counter` (i=2) is  checked against `end` (3).
If `counter` (i=2) `<=` `end` (3) (**TRUE**), go to next round, else exit (**FALSE**).
**Round 2:**
`counter` is 2 (i=2).
`Msgbox` displays `counter` (i=2).
`Next` increases `counter` (i=3).
`counter` (i=3) is  checked against `end` (3).
If `counter` (i=3) `<=` `end` (3) (**TRUE**), go to next round, else exit (**FALSE**).
**Round 3:**
`counter` is 3 (i=3).
`Msgbox` displays `counter` (i=3).
`Next` increases `counter` (i=4).
`counter` (i=4) is checked against `end` (3).
If `counter` (i=4) `<=` `end` (3) (**FALSE**), go to next round, else exit (**TRUE**).
**Exit**
The outside `Msgbox` displays `counter` (i=4).

**Two important things**:
The loop will run `end - start + 1` times (rounds).
The `counter` will end up being `end + 1`.

**This will not always be true**, e.g. if you put i = 5000 into the loop, `counter` (i) will end up being equal to 5001.
If you put `i = i - 1` into the loop, you will end up with an endless loop: `counter` will always be 1.
If you put i = i - 2  into the loop, the loop will run until it exceeds the value limit of the variable and finish in an Overflow error.

**To conclude**, once the loop has started (`start` has been written to `counter`), it has 'forgotten' about `start`, so `counter` can be less than `start`.
But `end` will be 'relevant' until the loop is exited which will happen as soon as `counter` is greater than `end` (or `Exit For` is used).

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your program may tell that you want to iterate through the existing rows. In this case I would recommend a `For Each` loop:

```
Dim varRow As Variant: For Each varRow In sht.UsedRange.Rows
    If varRow.Row = 2 Or varRow.Row = 5 Then
        varRow.EntireRow.Insert XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, False ' Insert row above this
        varRow.offsert(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, False ' Insert row below this
    End If
    Debug.Print varRow.Address
Next varRow
```

I tested the code, and it runs until the last old row.

Answer (score -1):

## Insert Rows Union feat. the Union Range Alternator

Since the mystery of 'instructions that may or may not insert new rows' has not yet been revealed, I came up with my own 'instructions'.

### Description

Loops through used rows of a worksheet and checks if the current row number is in a list (array) and inserts a row before (above) the found row.

### The Code

```vb
Sub InsertRowsUnion()

    Dim sht As Worksheet  ' Source Worksheet
    Dim rngU As Range     ' Union Range
    Dim vnt As Variant    ' Value Array
    Dim i As Long         ' Source Worksheet Row Counter
    Dim URA As Long       ' Union Range Alternator

    ' Create an array of values.
    vnt = Array(5, 6, 12, 17)

    Set sht = Worksheets(2)

    ' Loop through rows of Source Worksheet.
    For i = 1 To sht.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        ' Check if current row can be found in Value Array.
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(i, vnt, 0)) Then
            ' Check if Union Range already contains a range.
            If Not rngU Is Nothing Then ' Already CONTAINS a range.
                URA = URA Mod 2 + 1
                ' Add cell at the intersection of current row and
                ' column URA (1 or 2, "A" or "B") and 'renew' the reference
                ' to Union Range.
                Set rngU = Union(rngU, sht.Cells(i, URA))
              Else ' Does NOT contain a range. Only the first time.
                ' Add cell at the intersection of current row and
                ' column 2 ("B") and create a reference to Union Range.
                Set rngU = sht.Cells(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Debug.Print rngU.Address

    ' Check if Union Range contains a range.
    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        ' Insert rows.
        rngU.EntireRow.Insert  ' .Hidden = True , .Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

### Remarks

- The `Union Range Alternator` (`URA`) is used if e.g. two (or more)
  consecutive cells (rows) are added to `Union`, `Union` would
  translate it to e.g. `A2:A3` and two consecutive rows would be
  inserted before the 2nd row, while we wanted to add a row before the
  2nd row and another before the 3rd row. `URA` is not needed
  (decreases efficiency) if `Hidden` or `Delete` are used instead of
  `Insert`.
- If you want to insert the rows after (below) the found cells (rows), in the two `Set rngU` lines, replace `i` with `i + 1`.